# UILabel's content size doesn't update after font scales down automatically

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uilabel

I have a UILabel in a header that's supposed to scale down when the page is scrolled. 
I achieve that with with auto layout - I scale down the whole header's height, which in turn scales down the label's height and then the font size decreases automatically.

The problem is that the content size doesn't change with the the lable's font size resulting in a funny looking view.

How do you make the content size smaller with the label's font change?

Here's the UILabel's definition:

```
let lblGroup = UILabel()
lblGroup.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
lblGroup.numberOfLines = 0
lblGroup.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
```

This is the original layout:
[image]

This is after the scroll:
[image]

They both share the same content size:
[image]

Comment: If you have the `width` constraint hardcoded to 149 it will always be 149.

Comment: The width is not set by me at all

Comment: Isn't that a screenshot of the constraint, showing the width set at 149?

Comment: Yeah, set by iOS automatically. you can tell by the "(content size)" part